# authenticate a user and generate / store session id

Tags: python, python-3.x, authentication, session

I'm building a small user platform in VueJS with a Python micro-service (falcon), and postgres database.  I'd like some help understanding the proper flow for generating the session id, and whether there are any suggestions as to how I can improve this approach and if there are any other approaches I should consider.

Currently, these are the steps taken for authentication.

```
1)user sends username/password
2)if user exists in db, then I am generating a session_id (example: c8c83009-55b6-442a-b934-c6629aa20ac6)
the api layer stores this session_id in redis, and I would plan to pull in some relevant session data like email address, name, address, billing account id for stripe, etc.
3)I return the session_id as a cookie (set-cookie). Then on future requests for each page, the browser is passing the api the cookie (with session_id) with this session id.
```

Is this the proper approach? Should the session_id be "plain text" format as shown above, or do I need to md5 or apply some type of hashing to it? With a caching store like redis, should I be saving the session_id as the key, or maybe it would be best to use the email address instead, but keep the session_id as one of the values. Is this the typical approach for issuing a session_id, or should there be something additional that goes with the session_id in case someone was to get a hold of the session_id?

Just curious to see how people are handling sessions for authentication and authorization, and if you have any good resources which you feel would be useful please share!

Answer (score 0):

If your site uses `http://`  the transport is not secured and regardless of if you hash or not your sesssionsID - you are transmitting it in plaintext. Anybody capturing that can issue requests with that token - so the first step would be to secure your transport by using `https://` ... until you do that, it does not really matter.

If you use `htpps://` using outdated MD5 for hashing the session-token does not give you "more" security because the same applies. If someone is smart enough to man-in-the-middle / XHRs your `https://` he can get the token or the hashed token and you got the same problem as above.

Transmitting the password salted and hashed (not md5, try SHA-256) on the other hand should "ensure" that *if* someone gets his hands on it, it is not *reverseable* into clear text again. If salting does not change with client/time/random cookie value the request could be replayed to gain access - but if you somehow get a "sufficient" but "shortlived" (handwavium@work) salting and hashing might / would / should improve security.

---

Ressources:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_application_security
- Plenty of results for google `how to secure my website access token`, f.e [dzone.com Article All you need to know about user session security](https://dzone.com/articles/all-you-need-to-know-about-user-session-security)